# Adding a field to tx_news is causing template not found error

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, tx-news

I'm trying to add a thumbnail field to tx_news file records but when I do try use the new field I get an error.

These are the steps I've taken,

[image: added column to sql]

Added the column to sql

[image: add tca]

Add the new field to the tx_news_domain_model_file tca

[image: new field is working]

I now have the new field in my news file record.

[image: File.php]

Then I added my thumbnail stuff to Classes/Domain/Model/File.php. Then I use the new variable in my template {relatedFile.thumbnail}

[image: my error]

This is the error I now get on the frontend when I view a single news. The news display works when I remove the new field.

I am using Typo3 6.1 with:

- Fluidpages 2.1.0
- Fluidcontent 3.1.0
- Flux 6.0.3
- VHS 1.8.5

Answer (score 0):

You are just seeing the error message about not finding a template to display the real error message. Without the real error message, it is impossible to help you.

Did you clear all caches (install tool) or truncated the extbase reflection and the fluid rendering caches? To be sure, also clear `typo3temp/Cache/*`.